# how to stop the favicon from refreshing

Tags: html, favicon

How can I stop my site from reloading the favicon?

For Example, Say I am on /index.html and I click on a link going to /nav.
They have the same favicon and I am using `/favicon.ico` but they still reload the favicon.
I see some sites like undraw.co, for example, do not reload the favicon when you click a link.

Here is some of what I'm trying:

index.html/nav favicon:

```html
 <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Why is this not working for me? And how do I fix it?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm still at a loss for this.

Comment: This could help you a little: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/how-do-i-modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page/1898107#1898107

Comment: I'm browsing undraw.co with Chrome and I notice an access to favicon.ico in DevTools>Network each time I click a link.